# Where did the iTunes visualizers/32-bit go?

Tags: itunes, macos

There used to be 5 built-in visualizers in iTunes, but now I can only find 2 — Visualizer and Classic Visualizer. I am told that the other Visualizers reappear if you run in 32-bit mode, but I can't find 32-bit mode anymore either. Did Apple take it away in Sierra or earlier?

macOS Sierra, iTunes 12.7